# What's the right way to make a null distribution?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

I want to run an a/b test. I'd like to check if my results in the experimental variant are extreme, under the null hypothesis. I haven't created my sample, yet, and I'd like to do a power analysis to make sure that I have a large enough sample in my experiment.

My test is whether more users convert on my new landing page than my old one.

I'm reading [this paper](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~bacraig/SCS/Power%20and%20Sample%20Size%20Calculation.doc) about power analysis and sample size calculation.

[image: an]

It assumes that I know the population variance under the null hypothesis, but I have no idea how much variability there is. If I ran the experiment 100 times, I can guess it'll be normally distributed since the central limit theorem and that gets me part of the way there, I think?

How do I create the null sampling distribution so that I can calculate the power function?

Comment: If you don't know the variance, presumably you'll be using a t-test rather than a z-test; alternatively if you're relying on CLT + Slutsky's theorem to get to a z-test (n=100 may or may not be sufficient to do this) then you are treating the sample variance as if it were the population variance.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. I run a t-test to see if the statistic is different between the control and experimental groups. The idea is that there is a distribution of statistics where there is no difference, the null distribution, and my p-value determines the likelihood I observed the difference, given the null is true.

Comment: I did a datacamp class and they made the null distribution by creating permutations of the observations, which didn't make much sense to me.

Comment: If that's an accurate take on it, how do I do a power analysis in an experiment where I use a t-test?

Comment: 1. Getting p-values from permuting the data is perfectly sensible -- that's a permutation test. 2. The p-value is the probability of a difference (from the situation under the null) at least as large as the observed one. 3. When you say "how do I do a power analysis" ... what are you doing exactly? [To me a power analysis might be to compute a power curve (as a function of effect size) at some sample size, or to compute a power curve as a function of sample size at some effect size, but some people seem to use it to mean computing a sample size to achieve a given power at some effect size]

Comment: Note that permutation tests are justified in a somewhat different way to the "usual" tests. For example they don't necessarily rely on random sampling of the population; they can rely on random assignment to treatment even without being a random sample of the population and show a significant effect (the difficulty may be in arguing that the result extends to the broader population).

Comment: For "how do I do a power analysis", I'd like to predict the right size sample for my a/b test to have a power of .8 or greater. I found an R package called `pwr` that does "power analysis along the lines of cohen (1988)". It looks like I can run a `pwr.ttest` and give it the effect size and it will tell my the required sample size `pwr.t.test(d=0.1,power=0.8,sig.level=0.05,type="two.sample",alternative="greater")`

Comment: It looks like I choose the test according to what statistical test I'm doing. A/B test will always be a t-test assuming the samples are normally distributed, but it's nice to know that I can do a power analysis in case I'll be doing an anova or regression. https://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html

Comment: Hi -- if you want proper answers to the stuff about the sample size calculation, could you edit your question?